# How can I force chrome to save email passwords?

Tags: google-chrome, password

I am running Ubuntu Quantal (12.10) with Chrome (not Chromium) installed via terminal. Unfortunately, when it comes to mail automatic log in, for some reason Chrome doesn't offer to save passwords, which is really frustrating if one uses mail a lot, I do not want to write my username and passwords every time I check my mail. Looked everywhere and I can't find a solution.

Comment: Do you use the "keep me signed in" option ticked? BTW, Chrome and Chromium will behave the same way in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

See the image. Do you have similar settings in the Advanced Settings section?

[image: Settings to save passwords]